# When to use List<T>, IEnumerable<T> and ArrayList

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, ienumerable

My question is really simple. When should I use List, IEnumerable and ArrayList.

Here's my scenario. I'm working in a Web app using LINQ. Information is returned as a IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<Inventory> result = from Inventory i in db where....
```

I'm not sure how IEnumerable works, but every operation takes a lot of time to execute. More specifically, result.Count(), result.ElementAt(i), result.ToList, etc, each operation takes a considerable amount of time.

So, I was wondering if I should treat this as a List by doing result.ToList, instead of working with the IEnumerable variable.

Thanks!

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using (i.e. where is the data coming from)? What size is the list?

Comment: But `result.ToList` would work with IEnumerable in this case.

Comment: What @L.B is trying to say is that the slowness you are seeing is not because of using `IEnumeralbe<T>`.

Comment: IEnumerable does not "works" by itself. It depends on its implementation.  `List<T>` **is** `IEnumerable` as it implements it.

Comment: @Oded I'm using db4o as my database engine. The size of the list varies, but around 800 items. I addded a foreach sentence and debugged my IEnumerable list. The first object (index 0) takes a lot of time to load, but then it works OK. If I use a List element, result.ToList() takes some time, but at least accessing the elements will not be a problem

Comment: Is the Linq to SQL to get your Inventory collection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you're doing correctly, you have a query like `from Inventory i in db select i` and then you do several operations on the result:

```
var count = result.Count();
var fifth = result.ElementAt(5);
var allItems = result.ToList();
```

Now consider what happens when you have the query as different types:

- `IQueryable<T>`

  ```
  var result = from Inventory i in db select i;
  IQueryable<Inventory> result = from Inventory i in db select i;
  ```

  The two lines above are the same. They don't actually go to the database, they just create a representation of the query. If you have this, `Count()` will execute an SQL query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Inventory`, `ElementAt(5)` will execute another query that takes only the fifth item in the table and `ToList()` will execute something like `SELECT * FROM Inventory`, but that's what we want here.
- `IEnumerable<T>`

  ```
  IEnumerable<Inventory> result = from Inventory i in db select i;
  ```

  Doing this again does not go the database, it only creates a representation of the query. But it's a representation that can't use the methods specific to `IQueryable<T>`, so any LINQ operation will enumerate the collection, which will execute an SQL query like `SELECT * FROM Inventory`.

  So, for the example: `Count()` will execute the `SELECT * …` query only to count the items in the result. `ElementAt(5)` will execute the whole query *again*, only to throw away all items except for the fifth. And `ToList()` will execute the query *one more time*.
- `List<T>`

  ```
  List<Inventory> result = (from Inventory i in db select i).ToList();
  ```

  This will actually execute the `SELECT * FROM Inventory` query immediately and *once*. All operations you do with `result` won't touch the database, they will be done in-memory.

What should you take away from this? First, *never use `IEnumerable<T>` as the type of the database query*. It has horrible performance.

If you want to make several distinct operations on the result, using `IQueryable<T>` might be the best solution.

If you want to retrieve the whole result anyway, use `ToList()` (or `ToArray()`) as soon as possible and then work with the resulting `List<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

Never use ArrayList. ArrayList is kept for compatibility with pre-.NET 2.0 was. It's equivalent to `List<object>`, and there's no reason not to use the generic types in any normal situation.

It seems from your code sample that you're using LINQ to SQL or a similar framework to fetch data from the DB. In this case, the `select` statement itself doesn't bring the data, it just constructs the query. When you call a method like Count() or ToList(), it fetches the data - which is why it seems slow. It's not any slower, it's just the lazy loading in action.

The advantage of using IEnumerable is that you don't have to load all the data at once. If you just query with a specific `where` clause, or call Take(1) to get the first element, the LINQ provider should be smart enough to only fetch the necessary elements from the DB. But if you call Count() or ToList(), it has to retrieve the entire dataset. If you find yourself needing that sort of information, you'll probably want to call `ToList` or `ToArray` and do the rest of your work on the in-memory list, so you don't have to hit the DB again.

Answer (score 2):

Your query gets executed only when you call ToList() or other similar method.

This is called [Deffered Execution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx).

Use IEnumerable whenever it is possible for your `result`. Performance of execution LINQ doen't depend on what you use for `result`, because in the end it is treated as IEnumerable anyway.

But LINQ performance depends on underlying data.

[WAS EDITED WITH DETAILS]

Comment: This is wrong. Performance of executing a database LINQ query can depend hugely on whether you use `IQueryable<T>` (efficient SQL query), `IEnumerable<T>` (possibly very inefficient SQL query) or `List<T>` (by calling `ToList()` once, possibly very inefficient once, fast after that).

Comment: @Andriy I've debugged my code and performance of LINQ is OK, the problem is when accessing elements in my IEnumerable variable, or any other methods.

Comment: Yes, but it depends on underlying data, from which query is done. Question is about result variable, as I understood.

Comment: @Gonzalo, so maybe we deal with Deferred execution, if I understand your problem: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between using an IEnumerable or a IList is actually quite simple (on the surface).

You should look at the contract defined by both interfaces. An IEnumerable simply allows you to enumerate over a sequence. In other words, the only way to access data is by using an Enumerator, typically in a foreach loop. So a naive implementation of the count function would be something like:

```
public static int Count(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    int count = 0;
    foreach(var item in myEnumerable)
    {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This means that the time needed to calculate the number of items in your enumerable will increase linearly with the number of items. Also, because this is not stored in any way internally, you will have to do this loop every time you want a count.

An IList already exposes a Count property. This is part of the contract. To implement Count() on that you would simply wrap a call to the Count property. This will take the same amount of time regardless of the number of items.

A simple way to think about this is (especially using Linq) to think of an IEnumerable as a specification of the items you need. As long as you don't access the data, it will cost you hardly any time to build. Once you start enumerating (anything that returns something else than an IEnumerable basically) the code will execute and it could take some time.

As for your context, what I usually like to do is keep the Linq execution within the controller. So I do my query building, and then ToList or ToArray it before sending it off to the view. The reason is quite simple: if I have to do anything more than simply accessing the data in the view it means I am doing too much in my view. I am now forced to move that logic to my controller action, keeping my views as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a linq expression against a Linq query provider, the result will be a an [`IQueryable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx), which is an extension of `IEnumerable<T>`.

Each time you iterate over an `IQueryable<T>`, the Linq query provider will execute the query against the underlying datasource. Therefore, if you want to iterate through the result more that once, it can be more efficient to convert it to a list first (`.ToList()`).

Note that when you convert your result to a list, you should use the actual members of `List<T>` instead of the extension methods of `IEnumerable<T>`. For example `list.ElementAt(i)` and `list.Count()` are both executed in `O(n)` time, while `list[i]` and `list.Count` are executed in constant time.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Generic** Lists/IEnumerable whenever possible.

Avoid `ArrayList`. This can cause boxing for value types and casting for reference types. `IEnumerable` is the same - best be avoided unless you deal with objects.

`IEnumerable<T>` exhibits very nice covariance, contravariance features. Yet it displays `delayed execution` which is a curse as much as blessing.

`List<T>` is better for internal use while exposing interfaces as `IEnumerable<T>`. `List<T>` does not support contravariance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on which to use is "it depends, but mostly use List".

Based on the full contents of your question (long delays running .Count() and other methods), you should first do a toList() on the results of the query, then use that for any further access.

Here's why. That IEnumerable is pretty much a query. Since the data being queried can change between runs of the query, ever single method call on that IEnumerable results in another database lookup.

So each time you call .Count(), someone has to go to the database and get a count of all objects matching your query. Each time you do a elementAt(x), even if x doesn't change, someone still needs to go through the database and get whatever is there because IEnumerable cannot assume that the data hasn't changed.

On the other hand, if you've gotten a snapshot of your query using List, then getting Count or accessing random elements is pretty fast.

So, which to use - it depends. If each time you access the IEnumerable, you need to know what's in the database (or whatever data source) NOW, then you've got to use IEnumerable. If you only care about what was there at the time you executed the initial query or need to perform operation over a consistent (and/or static) source of data, use List. You'd still take a time hit on your first access, but everything else will be fast.